# how to make sum in one label swift

Tags: sum, label, swift2

I tried to make sum but its keep telling me that I can't sum int to a string , whats wrong with my code ?!

I need to put a number in a textfield then I put another number to be sum in the label , so I need to take the number in the label and sum with the new entry , Am I right ?

```
@IBOutlet weak var oursResult: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var theirsResult: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var note: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var oursInput: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var theirsInput: UITextField!
@IBAction func calButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    var enteredOurs = Int(oursInput.text!)
    var enteredTheirs = Int(theirsInput.text!)
    if enteredOurs != nil {
        if  oursResult.text != nil { // my problem starts from here 
            var firstMove = (oursResult.text! as NSString)
            var secondMove = enteredOurs
            var sum = firstMove + secondMove
            oursResult.text = "\(sum)"
        }
        oursResult.text = "\(enteredOurs!)" 
    }else { 
        note.text = "please enter a number"
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your variable `firstMove` is `NSString`..so you can't applied operator to different operands like NSString and Int.

So Just change....

```
 var firstMove = Int(oursResult.text!)  // instead of (oursResult.text! as NSString)
 var secondMove = enteredOurs
 var sum = firstMove + secondMove  // Now both variables are Integer
```

Comment: it worked but not as I expected because the first entry is wrong , when I put 1 it gave me 8 , 2 gave me 9 , 3 gave me 80 and so on, and whenever I put the second number it will make sum , but the first gave it to me in wrong way